# How to reference self in flask route method?

Tags: flask

For example, this pattern is usually accomplished with globals. How to use attributed?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app._this_thing = None

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    self._this_thing = 123
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the global variable `current_app` (see [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.current_app)) and access it in your function like this:

```
from flask import Flask, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)
app._this_thing = 'Hello world!'
    
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return current_app._this_thing
```

Saving the this as `so.py` and starting it like this

```
$ FLASK_APP=so.py flask run
```

then returns the expected response:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000
Hello world!
```